# Netbeans Ignoring CSS Styling in HTML5 Application

Tags: css, html, netbeans

I've been fooling around with HTML5 applications in Netbeans 8.0, and things were going fine until the thing just decided to ignore my stylesheet.  It recognizes thing that are *outside* the stylesheet, but anything in it is cast aside when the thing runs.  I've checked for syntax-related errors and whatnot, but can't seem to find anything (or my newbie eye has totally missed it).  No amount of hitting the "undo" button has reverted the problem, either, and I haven't been able to find solutions online.  I'm using Chrome to view the application through that netbeans extension, if it means anything, and I've provided the CSS and HTML I've been tinkering with below.  Can anyone lend me a hand?

**CSS**

```
//THE SCROLL BG
#backgroundthing {
    background-image:url("databasePics/bgimgwide.png");
    height: 700px;
    width: 999px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-999;
}

//HEADER ONE
h1 {
    font-size:40pt;
    font-family:Abadi MT Condensed Light;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#ffffff;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
}

//STANDARD TEXT
#body_text {
    font-family:Arial Narrow;
    font-size:12pt;
    color:#ffffff;

}

//TRANSLUCENT WHITE AREA WHERE CONTENT IS HELD
#textarea {
     height:500px;
     width:630px;
     background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
     margin-left:200px;
     margin-top:70px;
     padding:5px;
}

//IMAGE OF CHARACTERS AT THE BOTTOM OF TEAM PAGES
 #teamPerson {
    border-radius:100%;
    border:5px solid;
    transition: .8s all ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: .8s all ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: .8s all ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-transition: .8s all ease-in-out
}

//HOVER EFFECT FOR THE ABOVE
#teamPerson:hover {
    border-radius:100%;
    border:5px solid #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ffffff;
}
```

**HTML** (there are 3 different HTML files here, but I couldn't get 'em to display in different chunks.  A new file starts at every .  I was messing around in the third one when the problem arose, but I included the others just in case they're of any help.)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OC Team Database</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type ="text/css" rel ="stylesheet" href="mainCSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="backgroundthing">
            <div id = "textarea">
                <!-- THE IFRAME WHERE EVERYTHING IS LOADED INTO -->
                <iframe name = "loadedPage" src ="landingPage.html" scrolling="no" style="width: 630px; height: 500px; border: 0; overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type ="text/css" rel ="stylesheet" href="mainCSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <!-- TITLE + INSTRUCTIONS -->
                <div style="margin-top:-35px;"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
                <div id = "body_text" style = "margin-top:-30px;"><center>Please select one of the teams below.

                    <br><br>

                    <!-- TABLE WITH TEAM NAMES -->

                    <table width = "100%"><tr>
                            <td width ="33%" height ="190px" align="center"><a href="teamCGRY.html" target="loadedPage">CGRY</a></td>
                            <td width ="33%" height ="190px" align="center"><a href="teamHRBS.html" target="loadedPage">HRBS</a></td>
                            <td width ="33%" height ="190px" align="center"><a href="teamPLTN.html" target="loadedPage">PLTN</a></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td width ="33%" height ="190px" align="center"><a href="teamRUST.html" target="loadedPage">RUST</a></td>
                            <td width ="33%" height ="190px" align="center"><a href="teamVNOM.html" target="loadedPage">VNOM</a></td>
                            <td width ="33%" height ="190px" align="center"><a href="teamXAFR.html" target="loadedPage">XAFR</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type ="text/css" rel ="stylesheet" href="mainCSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <!-- TITLE -->
            <div style="margin-top:-35px;"><h1>Team CGRY</h1></div>

            <!-- ABOUT TEXT -->
            <div id ="body_text" style="height:260px; width:100%;margin-top:-20px;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style = "width:83%; height:260px">
                            <div style="height:260px; overflow:auto; border-right:1px solid #ffffff">
                                Detailed information about the team.
                            </div>
                        </td>
                            <td style = "width:17%; height:260px" valign = "top">
                                <b>Pronunciation:</b> 
                                <br>"Sea grey"
                                <br><br><b>Team Colour:</b> 
                                <br>Blue-Grey
                                <br><br><b>Status:</b> 
                                <br>Active
                                <br><br><b>Affiliation:</b> 
                                <br>Beacon Academy
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <!-- TEAM MEMBER PICTURES AND SHIT -->
            <table style="width:100%; margin-top:15px">
                <tr>
                    <td style = "width:25%; height:100px; text-align:center"><img src="databasePics/squarePlaceholder.png" style="border-radius:100%; border:5px solid #ffffff;" alt = "image"></td>
                    <td style = "width:25%; height:100px; text-align:center"><img src="databasePics/squarePlaceholder.png" style="border-radius:100%; border:5px solid #ffffff;" alt = "image"></td>
                    <td style = "width:25%; height:100px; text-align:center"><img src="databasePics/squarePlaceholder.png" style="border-radius:100%; border:5px solid #ffffff;" alt = "image"></td>
                    <td style = "width:25%; height:100px; text-align:center"><img src="databasePics/squarePlaceholder.png" style="border-radius:100%; border:5px solid #ffffff;" alt = "image"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you are not commenting out our css correctly, do this

```
/*THE SCROLL BG*/
```

Comment: Ha, I feel dumb now.  Thanks for pointing out my stupid mistake :).  I dunno why it only started acting up now, though--I had the "//" there pretty much the whole time.

Comment: No problem, its nice when its easy :)